# Nodejs/Express - How to access Mongodb by Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I currently have problems in build a REST API. I tried to access the data from Mongodb by mongoose.Schema; however, the response from the API always returns [].

Here is my route:

```
const express =  require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const course = require('../models/api')


router.get('/', async function(req, res){
    try {
        const course_list = await course.find()
        res.json(course_list)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err.message}); 
    }
})
module.exports = router;
```

Here is my models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: [String],
    teacher: [String],
    day: String,
    time: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('class', courseSchema);
```

Here is what my database look like: the collections is named 'class'

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e871e7e43b612fa0b1bd745"),
        "name" : [
                "Network Security",
                "CS0337"
        ],
        "teacher" : [
                "hpchen",
                "CHEN HEN PEI"
        ],
        "day" : "Tue",
        "time" : [
                "13:00-13:50",
                "13:55-14:45"
        ]
}
```

[The response from API is an empty [ ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JdtT.png)

I already tried:

1. { any: [] }
2. { any: Array }

I hope somebody will help me.

Comment: `await course.find({})` you need to add a empty object as first paramiter if you want to find all entrys. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: Mongoose will attempt to pluralize the model-name when mapping it to a collection. Your collection should likely be named `classes`. How did the collection get created (by mongoose or did you create it yourself)?

Comment: The collection (class) is created by myself.

Comment: @Marc still get empty [ ]